# Python Selenium Webdriver: return error after returning few elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to  retrieve the information related to reviewers posted on google play store. I tried to extract the name of reviewers and rating given by reviewer. Code returns the first set of information then it returns the error. I tried to debug but couldnt fix it. Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverLocation)
driver.get('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.getsomeheadspace.android&showAllReviews=true')
driver.implicitly_wait(20) 
parentElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h3[contains(text(),"User reviews")]//parent::div/div[1]/div')

for child in parentElement.find_element_by_tag_name('div'):       
    name = child.find_element_by_class_name('X43Kjb').text
    indvd_rating = child.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="nt2C1d"]//div[@aria-label]').get_attribute('aria-label')
    print(name)
    print(indvd_rating)


driver.quit()
```

Error is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".X43Kjb"}
```

Could anyone point out where am I making the mistake?

Comment: I think this just means that you have a "div" section that doesn't happen to have an "X43Kjb" element.  Check your HTML and see.

Comment: @FrankMerrow you are right!!! Any suggestion how to fix the issue? Sorry for asking as I am new in learning Selenium Webdriver

Comment: Put a Python try/except block around the "find" that will catch only this error so that if it happens you can just ignore it.